# Javascript static and prototype mocking

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, static

I'm writing unit-tests for my Node.js/Express application with REST endpoints which retrieve stuff via Mongoose from db. Since I'm testing only route functions I want to mock Mongoose by providing custom request and response functions etc. I also had to mock my Person mongoose schema module with mockery.

Here is my api-endpoint functions:

```
    /* GET one person */
function getPerson(req, res, next) {
    Person.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, person) {
        if (!person) {
            res.status(404);
            res.json({
                message: "ERROR: Person with id: " + req.params.id + " was not found from database."
            })
        } else {
            res.json(person)
        }
    });

}

/* POST one person */
function postPerson(req, res, next) {
    console.log(Person);
    var p = new Person(req.body);
    p.save(function(err) {
        console.log(p);
        console.log(Person);
        if (err) {
            res.status(400);
            res.json(err);
        }
        else {
            var r = {
                message: "New person created",
                person: p
            };
            res.json(r);
            res.status(201);
        }
    });
}
```

The important part is that the Person schema can be called in two ways:

```
Person.save(function(){}) //static function
var p = new Person(req.body);
    p.save(function(err){}) //instance function
```

Here is my mockery mock for Mongoose schema of Person:

```
    function MockPerson(person) {

    this.content = {};
    for (var k in person) {
        if (person.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            this.content[k] = person[k];    //add person's properties here to simulate Mongoose's Object
        }
    }

}
MockPerson.prototype.find = function(params, callback) {
    console.log("mockfind");
    return null
};
//Ugly. Note that in JS prototype functions are accessible only from instances and statics only from class.
//Mongoose supports both Person.findOne and var p = new Person(); p.findOne() so we need both prototype and static functions
MockPerson.prototype.findOne = MockPerson.findOne = function(params, callback) {
    console.log("mockfindOne");
    callback(null, null);
};
MockPerson.prototype.save = MockPerson.save = function(callback) {
    console.log("mocksave");
    callback();
};
```

I'm still quite new with JS so I got a bit confused until I realized that prototype functions are only accessible in instances of Person and statics only from "class" Person. So this led me to add lines:

```
MockPerson.prototype.findOne = MockPerson.findOne = function(params, callback)
```

Maybe it's just me but that looks a bit dubious. Any ideas how I could refactor either my endpoint code or mocks or is this okay in your opinion?

Finally here is my work in progress Mocha test for this thing:

```
describe('personApiEndpoints', function() {
    before(function(){
        // The before() callback gets run before all tests in the suite. Do one-time setup here.
        mockery.enable({ useCleanCache: true });
        console.log("MOCKKAA");
        mockery.registerMock("../../models/person", MockPerson);
        endpoints = require("../routes/api/persons");
    });

    beforeEach(function(){
        // The beforeEach() callback gets run before each test in the suite.
    });

    it('return approriate error response when getPerson() fails', function(done) {
        var mockRequest = createMockRequest();
        var mockResponse = createMockResponse();
        endpoints.getPerson(mockRequest, mockResponse);
        expect(mockResponse.resStatus).to.equal(404);
        expect(mockResponse.resJson).to.deep.equal({ message: 'ERROR: Person with id: 12345678910 was not found from database.' });
        done();
    });

    it('return response when postPerson succeeds', function(done) {
        var mockRequest = createMockRequest();
        var mockResponse = createMockResponse();
        endpoints.postPerson(mockRequest, mockResponse);
        expect(mockResponse.resStatus).to.equal(201);
        expect(mockResponse.resJson.message).to.equal("New person created");
        expect(mockResponse.resJson.person.content).to.deep.equal(mockRequest.body);
        done();
    });

    after(function() {
        // after() is run after all your tests have completed. Do teardown here.
        mockery.deregisterAll();
        mockery.disable();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple HTTP return codes here in there in your code, but don't explain what each return code means.

I recommend creating an object of the error codes with descriptive names so you can use those in place of just the plain code; it'll aid your readability greatly.

Here is what I came up with:

```
var HTTP_CODES = {
    CLIENT = {
        NOT_FOUND: 404,
        BAD_REQUEST: 400
    },
    SUCCESS = {
        CREATE:201
    }
}
```

Then, you can easily access these codes like this, for example:

```
res.status(HTTP_CODES.CLIENT.NOT_FOUND);
```

Notice how I used all capitals for the naming? Generally across other languages, all capital letters is used for constant values.

---

From `postPerson`,

```
if (err) {
    res.status(400);
    res.json(err);
}
else { // <----------
    var r = {
        message: "New person created",
        person: p
    };
    res.json(r);
    res.status(201);
}
```

Typically, the `else {` will come on the same line as the close `}` of the preceding `if` statement.

You wrote it the correct way in `getPerson` so I don't know why you changed it.

---

```
    function MockPerson(person) {

    this.content = {};
    for (var k in person) {
```

The signature of `MockPerson` should not be indented.

---

> I realized that prototype functions are only accessible in instances
>   of Person and statics only from "class" Person

The line you entered after:

```
MockPerson.prototype.findOne = MockPerson.findOne = function(params, callback)
```

Looks perfectly fine to me. However, do you really need to have a method that can be accessed as static and from an instance?

You say in a comment:

```
//Mongoose supports both Person.findOne and var p = new Person(); p.findOne() so we need both prototype and static functions
```

"Mongoose **supports**...". I don't know much about Mongoose, but if it supports both, can't you choose one?